# Performance decrease in OpenMP with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I coded a basic example of openmp with VisualStudio 2013, the example is the calculate of the area under a curve. This is the secuencial implementation

```
int integral(int a, int b, int n_intervalos, int(*function)(int))
{
    int long_interv = (b - a) / n_intervalos;
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = a; i < b; i+=long_interv)
    {
        int h = function(i);
        suma += h * long_interv;
    }
    return suma;
}
```

when i go to test this code i use this dataset

```
int intg = integral(0, 120, 120, funcion);
```

I want to use OpenMP the increase the performance then I did the following function

```
void integralParalelo(int a, int b, int n_intervalos, int(*function)(int), int *area)
{
    int max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
    int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    int sub_intervalo = n_intervalos / max_threads;

    int long_interv = (a + b) / n_intervalos;
    int ini = thread_id * long_interv * sub_intervalo;
    int fin = sub_intervalo * long_interv + ini;
    int suma = integral(ini, fin, sub_intervalo, function);

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        (*area) = (*area) + suma;
    }
}
```

And I called this function in this way

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
    integralParalelo(0, 120, 120, funcion, &area);
}
```

But the parallel solution is slower than the secuencial solution in the test the times were

- secuencial: 0 miliseconds
- parallel: 25 miliseconds!!!!

Why this happens?

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and my computer is an AMD A10-5745M

Comment: It's hard for anything to beat "0 milliseconds"  ;)

Comment: jajaja, it's true but I expected 0 millisenconds to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably 2 things happening here.

The first is that you are treating OpenMP as MPI when it is unnecessary. In your case, all you really should be doing is parallelizing your for loop and remembering to perform a reduction for your `suma` variable. The way that you are calling OpenMP routines yourself and splitting up the domain looks much more like MPI code to me.

Secondly, you are working on too small of a dataset. What you really need to be doing is testing this when it takes 60+ seconds in serial code and then comparing the time to an OpenMP run with 4 processors. Remember that creating your team of threads takes time, and if each thread is doing very little work, then the majority of your time will be spent in startup.

Because you're doing so little actual work in the for loop, I suspect you won't get more than 2-3x performance with 4 cores.

I would suggest doing this:

```
int integralParallel(int a, int b, int n_intervalos, int(*function)(int))
{
    int long_interv = (b - a) / n_intervalos;
    int suma = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) reduction(+:suma)
    for (int i = a; i < b; i+=long_interv)
    {
        int h = function(i);
        suma += h * long_interv;
    }
    return suma;
}
```

and calling it exactly as you call the serial code. Specify `num_threads(4)` if you want, but it shouldn't be necessary as long as OpenMP is picking up your 4 cores.

Comment: When I increase the dataset the parallel program beats the secuencial, but I have another example (the mergesort problem) that in visual studio do not matter what I do the secuencial is better than the parallel, but when I run the program in linux with eclipse instead of windows with visual studio the parallel beats the secuencial somebody told me that is because visual studio dont use the real machine's cores, but I don't find this explanetion in any sites.

Comment: Mergesort is a very different algorithm that is not well suited for OpenMP because of its recursive nature. You can do this with OpenMP tasks, but its performance won't be optimal. And again, as I said in my answer, if each thread is doing very little work, you're never going to be getting great performance because too much time is spent in thread initialization/control as opposed to actually computing.

Comment: Ok that's fine, if each thread don't have enough work I can't note the diference, but, I can note the difference when I use Linux instead of Windows, with the same dataset the difference is huge in the performance between this operating systems.